# How to add parameters to a URL without reload

Tags: javascript, url, append

How to append and addparameters to a URL without reload allready containing other parameters
Ex.

> localhost:5147/website/paytm?sort=deals
>
> localhost:5147/website/paytm?sort=deals&cat=171
>
> localhost:5147/website/paytm?sort=deals&cat=171,168

or

> localhost:5147/website/paytm?cat=171
>
> localhost:5147/website/paytm?cat=171&sort=deals
>
> localhost:5147/website/paytm?cat=171&sort=deals,offers
>
> localhost:5147/website/paytm?cat=171,191&sort=deals,offers

Answer (score 0):

Yoa can use the methods `pushState` and `replaceState` from the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.pushState`

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Url will be change without reloading, also you can use to event popstate to update your State App.
doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate